# Cache Manifest ignore local version

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

i was wondering is there a way in HTML5 cache manifest when is online to ignore the local version of a site, and use dynamic created site, and when is offline use the local version?

Answer (score 0):

no if you use cache manifest  all thing freeze even you be online but if you change the cache manifest file and edit it and update it then if user press F5 tow time then your dynamic "web page" be refresh.

## not "network" and not "prefer-online" don't help you to save your *.js And *.css and *.jpg on cache but have a  dynamic and automatic "web page(html,php,asp)"

all thing be freeze

sadly "cache manifest" is some thing like wood